# PHP-Pagination not working after sorting

Tags: php, mysql, html

HI i have a working **php based** pagination which works fine, but when i sort data by sorting links pagination dosen't works..

sorting method i used has direct link sorting with mysql query.

please see what i am doing wrong.

**my complete code so far**

```
    <?php 
    $table='mytable';
    $pagename = "is-test.php";
$db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result1);
$numrows = $row[0];
$rowsperpage = 5;
$totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);
if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])) {
$currentpage = (int) mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);
} else {
$currentpage = 1;
}
if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
$currentpage = $totalpages;
}
if ($currentpage < 1) {
$currentpage = 1;
}
$orderBy = array('id', 'title',);
$order = '';
if (isset($_GET['orderBy']) && in_array($_GET['orderBy'], $orderBy)) {
$order = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['orderBy']);
}else{
$order='id';
}
$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY $order ASC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
$startrow = ($currentpage-1) * $rowsperpage;

////////////////////////LINKS FOR SORTING///////////////////////
         echo "<a href=orderBy=id,>id:</a>";
         echo "<a href=orderBy=title,>title:</a>";
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////PAGINATION///////////////////////////
echo " <li><a href='$pagename?orderBy=$order,page=$totalpages'>$totalpages</a></li> ";


if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
$nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
echo " <li><a href='$pagename?orderBy=$order,page=$nextpage'>Next&raquo;&raquo;</a></li> ";
}

if($currentpage<$totalpages){
for ($x = ($currentpage - 3); $x < (($currentpage + 3) + 1); $x++) {
if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
if ($x == $currentpage) {
echo " <li id='pcurrent'><a href='$pagename?orderBy=$order,page=$x'>$x</a></li>";
} else {
echo " <li><a href='$pagename?orderBy=$order,page=$x'>$x</a></li> ";
}}}  
}

if ($currentpage > 1){
$prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
echo " <li><a href='$pagename?page=$prevpage'>&laquo;&laquo;Prev</a></li> ";
} 
if ($currentpage > 5) {
echo "<li><a href='$pagename?page=1'>1</a></li> ";
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Have you looked at the logs? Do you have a column called `title` in your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just saw that:
you have commas instead of & in your URL calls:

```
echo " <li><a href='$pagename?orderBy=$order,page=$nextpage'>Next&raquo;&raquo;</a></li> ";
```

change to:

```
echo " <li><a href='$pagename?orderBy=$order&page=$nextpage'>Next&raquo;&raquo;</a></li> ";
```

- change the other lines having this problem also

Comment: do you get any rows (number)? what $values do you have at the end? what do you mean not working? i tested this with my own pagination and cannot find an error.

Comment: pagination works when not using sorting(orderBy=$order removed from pagination links)i get values in pagination link as page1, page2 etc, then if i sort my recordset with sorting(orderBy=$order added to pagination links) pagination stops on sorted recordset and i get values in pagination link as orderBy=id,page1, orderBy=id,page2 etc but nothing happens

Comment: by changing $sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table"; with $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM $table"; pagination disappears.

Comment: ya its working now thanks for you time. also tell me how to further sort id and title in asending and descending this way i guess i have to work with ASC part in query the same way

Comment: thats right; just replace the static ASC in sql query(ies) with a $sortorder = $_GET["sortorder"]; This 'sortorder' will be sent from html like <a href='$pagename?orderBy=$order&page=$x&sortorder=ASC' as an example